# Error when trying to edit Content Query Web Part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I have a CQWP on my publishing site welcome page. When I go to edit the web part, I get a

> "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred." screen along with  Correlation ID: c6e03d9c-f1be-f0a0-ed33-e826db494520.

Does anyone know what is causing this? I've searched all over and can't find a solution.

Edit: I know think I found the error: "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." I still don't really know what that means or what to do.

Comment: Could you read the ULS file for the error detail and share it here....

Comment: @Pushpendra Definitely, except I'm not sure where to find that. I found some log files but I'm not sure they're the correct ones

Comment: @Pushpendra Ok I think I have it. Here's a little over a minute of logs. Click "toggle text wrapping" to make it readable. http://pastebin.com/jP0HAwy6

Comment: ULS file location : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs
Now get the latest modified file from here and search it by the correlation id.

Comment: Ok got it, with the correct correlation ID (different than in my OP) I get: http://pastebin.com/936BFbEb

Comment: so read the error.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew what to do with the correlation ID. I'm seeing "Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient)" and "[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 08/29/2013 14:17:19.94, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity". That doesn't really mean a whole lot to me

Comment: Actually I think I found it: "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." 

I'm still not totally sure what that means. By the way my previous comment was not meant to be sarcastic, I genuinely didn't know.

Comment: @Donald - I'm not sure that this error makes the problems.
Please give us a link to an updated log + correlation ID.

Comment: This post is old, but it could help someone as it did me: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/error-while-trying-edit-content-query-web-part-sharepoint-sahoo